# C char arrays for user input

Tags: arrays, c, io, char

I rarely log on and am very new to the C language, therefore I apologize if this is a duplicate question or if this is a silly query.

I'm currently learning C and am hitting a wall with strings. I understand that char arrays are used in place of strings in the language. My question is, is there a better way than to assign an arbitrary value when declaring a char[] for user input(i.e setting the size of the array to one value when the user might enter more or less than that amount of characters)?

Comment: You can use dynamic memory allocation and increase the size if the user enters more. There's a function `getline()` that does this automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on a POSIX system (basically anything that's not Windows), you can use [`getline(3)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) to do this. It will automatically allocate a buffer of the right size for you. Otherwise, you'll have to guess a length, allocate that, then read the input up to that length, and if you guessed wrong, use `realloc` to increase your guess and try again.

Comment: This works perfectly. I knew this was a silly query with an easy solution, but thanks for the help.

Comment: @ZachParker If my answer solved your problem, please accept it with the check mark.